# 4 pairs of identical pens.

Tags: combinatorics

Say I have 4 pairs of identical pens (say red, blue, green and black).

How many ways can I arrange them such that no two identical pens are next to each other?

Inclusion/Exclusion works (I get 864) but it seems a bit long. Is there another way of doing this problem?

I noticed that 864 is $4 \times 6^3$ or in other words $4 \times \binom{4}{2}^3$, perhaps this could be handy?

Comment: $864\neq 6^4$. Something is wrong there

Comment: My apologies! Have made the appropriate amendment.

Comment: Any pattern is one of a set of 24, which you get by swapping the colours around.  So RBRBGbGb is more-or-less the same pattern as RGRGBbBb.  There are 36 of these sets.

Answer (score 3):

Let 1 be the colour that appears first, 2 the second that appears second.

The first four pens can be 1212, 1213, 1231, 1232, 1234.

There is one way to complete 1212 - it must be 3434.

For both 1231 and 1232, there are 3 ways to place the 4s, and two ways to place the other two, so six ways each.

For 1234, there are 3*3*2*1 ways to place the other 4, so 18.

for 1213, there is one way that starts 12132, and four that start 12134.

In all, that is 1+6+6+18+5 = 36 patterns.

Multiply by 24 ways to replace numbers with colours, and you get 864

Answer (score 1):

The answer for $n$ pairs is tabulated at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A114938). The formula, $$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(-1)^{n-k}(n+k)!/2^k$$ is given, which strongly suggests Inclusion-Exclusion is the way to go. There is some other information on that page.