# Permutation problem - How many permutations are there such that no two numbers are immediately adjecent?

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the set of numbers 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4.

How many permutations are there such that no two identical numbers are immediately adjacent?

Comment: We just had exactly this problem yesterday. I'll see if I can find it. Here it is --- http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868930/4-pairs-of-identical-pens/

Comment: I think this is slightly different, if we consider numbers like 12, 31 etc. We want to avoid having 12123434, as there are identical numbers immediately adjacent. I we are talking about one-digit numbers however, it is the same.

Comment: @Martigan, you may be right --- but as OP writes "numbers" and then lists digits, I choose to interpret "numbers" as meaning "digits".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $\frac{8!}{2!^4}$ permutations in total.  $8$ symbols, in 4 pairs of 2 identical.

There are $\frac{4!}{1!3!}\frac{7!}{2!^3}$ ways at least 1 pair are coadjacent.  (Choose the pair, then treat it as one symbol).

There are $\frac{4!}{2!2!}\frac{6!}{2!^2}$ ways at least 2 pair are coadjacent.  (Choose the pairs, then treat each as one symbol).

There are $\frac{4!}{3!1!}\frac{5!}{2!}$ ways at least 2 pair are coadjacent.  (Choose the pairs, then treat each as one symbol).

There are $4!$ ways all pairs are coadjacent.

Then use the Principle of Inclusion Exclusion (PIE):